# Rails 4 S3 Error with Papreclip: NoSuchKey No Such Key

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm trying to determine why I'm getting this error when trying to upload a file with Paperclip to S3:

```
[AWS S3 404 0.994093 1 retries] head_object(:bucket_name=>"mybucketname",:key=>"development/images/26/original/picture") AWS::S3::Errors::NoSuchKey No Such Key
```

s3.yml

```
development:
  access_key_id: "xxxxxx"
  secret_access_key: "xxxxxx"

production:
  access_key_id: "xxxxxx"
  secret_access_key: "xxxxxx"
```

development.rb

```
 config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :bucket => 'mybucketname'
  }
```

user.rb

```
has_attached_file :image,
  :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/s3.yml",
    :s3_protocol => 'https',
    :path => ":rails_env/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
    :bucket => "mybucketname",
    styles: { 
      medium: "300x300>", 
      thumb: "100x100>" }
```

gemfile

```
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.3"
gem 'aws-sdk-v1'
```

I've tried removing the `path` and `s3_protocol`, but I get a similar error.

I tried moving the access keys into `development.rb`.  Also, I have temporarily set the bucket permissions to allow everyone to upload.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](http://www.drails.com/en/articles/2-amazon-s3-configuration-for-rails-and-paperclip).  In setting up my bucket, I didn't set-up my security policy.